# Dynamic Labels in Angular Material mdSelect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have problem with angular material.
I want to use Angular Material `md-select` directive with dynamic text in `label`. It seams that their directive creates copy of the html `label` text and put in in its `span` so after scope value is updated it is updating value in hidden `label` but not in their `span` (it is updating in after you open and close select list). Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong? If it is a bug does anybody see a nice way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

JS:

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
              $timeout(function(){
                $scope['select_n_letter'] = 'Lorem ipsum';
              }, 500);
            })
        ;
  ;
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController" style="padding-top: 50px">
    <form name="a_form">
       <md-input-container>        
        <label>{{select_n_letter}}</label>        
        <md-select 
            required
            name="letter"
            ng-model="letter"
            >
            <md-option value="option">selected</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </div>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbwjnWtbxUWGBqR247JI?p=preview)

**EDIT**

To see which span I mean please check the Plumker preview and see compiled directive HTML which looks like below:

```
 <md-select required="" name="letter" ng-model="letter" class="ng-pristine md-default-theme ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" id="select_3" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
    <md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_0">
        <span>/* text should goes here */</span>
        <span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </md-select-value>
</md-select>
```

Comment: Really unclear what you need, there isn't any `span` element

Comment: @Michelem There is a span. If you will check elements which directive creates after is compiled you will find the span containing text value of the label. Check Plumker link.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to show two identical md-select's ( apart from their label ). And use ng-show to switch between them. 
Another possibility, use a directive containing md-select inside.
Switch it on and off with ng-if with a different label as an input.

Hope this helps